# Is relying on deflection and not being honest the way forward?

Tags: clients

I work in an office where we are the contracted technical consultants programming and coding software for our client. The other day one of our systems went down (no one knows why, despite our best efforts, but it only takes about 10 minutes to put back up and is used by at most ~20 people) and then a bug was found in one of the programs.

The client started to complain about this, and I tried to give honest positive answers, that I'd already written a patch for the program but I stumbled in explaining the reasons for the system going down.

My colleague jokingly said 'Well, it's a friday, we thought you might want to head home early'. The client laughed, and went back to work.

As a client facing consultant, do I need rely on deflecting issues rather than addressing them?

Comment: Why is using humor to cool down a situation putting on a false face?

Comment: I think the way your colleague managed the situation was ok.

Comment: The way your co-worker handled that was perfect!

Comment: You are interpreting your colleagues' behaviour as "deflecting issues", and then you want an answer to the question "do I need rely on deflecting issues". If you interpret his behaviour another way you could ask a different question.

Comment: Sounds like the joke diffused a tense situation. I am not sure why that is a problem for you?

Comment: @JanDoggen yes I could? Is this an issue?

Comment: @Chad: It did, but it left me feeling slightly disappointed. I suppose I would, in the clients shoes, feel annoyed that my question was deflected. At the same time, I see it worked which confused me slightly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can *always* choose how to behave to people paying the bills - that fact is a solid reason that many of those people value customer service.

One thing that I found difficult to learn as a software engineer (and I've seen my peers have difficulty learning) is that clients often don't care about hows or whys. The hows and whys are what drive *our* work, clients more often than not want to ignore you.

They don't care how or why something broke, they just want to go back to ignoring you - and they can't do that until they're convinced it's fixed for good.

Sometimes that convincing requires mostly correct simplifications (which programmers consider untruths). Sometimes it requires overwhelming tech gibberish. Sometimes it requires the truth.

As a client facing consultant, your job is to satisfy the client's requirements - one of which is making them confident that your code is solid. Many times the easiest way to achieve that goal is via soft skills rather than technical.

Comment: I thnk you hit the nail squarely between the eyes there!